# Redraw a Neural Network Diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to modify the code from the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/362238/multiple-hidden-layers-in-neural-network-diagram) to fit my needs.

This is the modified code i made:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\def\layersep{2.5cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
   shorten >=1pt,->,
   draw=black,
    node distance=\layersep,
    every pin edge/.style={<-,shorten <=1pt},
    input neuron/.style={rectangle,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt,fill=green!50},
    output neuron/.style={circle,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt, fill=red!50},
    hidden neuron/.style={circle,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt, fill=purple!50},
    annot/.style={text width=4em, text centered}
]

    % Draw the input layer nodes
    \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,4}
    % This is the same as writing \foreach \name / \y in {1/1,2/2,3/3,4/4}
        \node[input neuron, pin=left:$x_{\y}$] (I-\name) at (0,-\y) {};

    % set number of hidden layers
    \newcommand\Nhidden{3}

    % Draw the hidden layer nodes
    \foreach \N in {1,...,\Nhidden} {
       \foreach \y in {1,...,5} {
          \path[yshift=0.5cm]
              node[hidden neuron] (H\N-\y) at (\N*\layersep,-\y cm) {};
           }
    \node[annot,above of=H\N-1, node distance=1cm] (hl\N) {};
    }

%    % Draw the output layer node
%
    \node[output neuron,pin={[pin edge={->}]right:$y$}, right of=H\Nhidden-3] (O) {};

    % Connect every node in the input layer with every node in the
    % hidden layer.
    \foreach \source in {1,...,4}
        \foreach \dest in {1,...,5}
            \path (I-\source) edge (H1-\dest);

    % connect all hidden stuff
    \foreach [remember=\N as \lastN (initially 1)] \N in {2,...,\Nhidden}
       \foreach \source in {1,...,5}
           \foreach \dest in {1,...,5}
               \path (H\lastN-\source) edge (H\N-\dest);

    % Connect every node in the hidden layer with the output layer
    \foreach \source in {1,...,5}
        \path (H\Nhidden-\source) edge (O);

    % Annotate the layers
    \draw [very thick,decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt}] (2,0) -- (8,0);
    \node[annot,left of=hl1] {Input layer};
    \node[annot,right of=hl\Nhidden] {Output layer};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And here what i got so far:

[image]

So, i need help with the following:

1 - Fixing the brace (theres an arrow at the end of it), and writing `Hidden layers` above it;

2 - Below the `$x_{3}$` rectangle, i would like to add `\vdots` and change `$x_{4}$` to `$x_{m}$`;

3 - Making the output layer look like the input, *i.e.*, four circles `$y_{1}$`, `$y_{2}$`, `$y_{3}$` followed by `\vdots` and `$y_{k}$`.

Comment: See my answer below if it suits your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution, in respect to your original code. Just a few adjustments.

[image: Redraw a neural network diagram]

```
\documentclass{article}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/629645/204164

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\def\layersep{2.5cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
   shorten >=1pt,%->,
   draw=black,
    node distance=\layersep,
    every pin edge/.style={<-,shorten <=1pt},
    input neuron/.style={rectangle,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt,fill=green!50},
    output neuron/.style={circle,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt, fill=red!50},
    hidden neuron/.style={circle,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt, fill=purple!50},
    annot/.style={text width=4em, text centered}
]
    
    
    \begin{scope}[->]
    % Draw the input layer nodes
    \foreach \y in {1,...,4}
        {
        \if\y4
            \node[input neuron, pin=left:$x_{m}$] (I-\y) at (0,-\y) {}; 
        \else  
            \node[input neuron, pin=left:$x_{\y}$] (I-\y) at (0,-\y) {};
        \fi
        }
    
    \path (I-3) --++ (-1,0) |- (I-4) node[pos=0.2] {\vdots};    %Vdots beteween x_3 and x_m
    
    % set number of hidden layers
    \newcommand\Nhidden{3}

    % Draw the hidden layer nodes
    \foreach \N in {1,...,\Nhidden} {
       \foreach \y in {1,...,5} {
          \path[yshift=0.5cm]
              node[hidden neuron] (H\N-\y) at (\N*\layersep,-\y cm) {};
           }
    \node[annot,above of=H\N-1, node distance=1cm] (hl\N) {};
    }

    % Draw the output layer nodes
    \foreach \t in {1,...,4}
        {
        \if\t4
            \node[output neuron,pin={[pin edge={->}]right:$y_k$}] (O-\t) at (\Nhidden*\layersep+\layersep,-\t) {}; 
        \else  
            \node[output neuron,pin={[pin edge={->}]right:$y_\t$}] (O-\t) at (\Nhidden*\layersep+\layersep,-\t) {};
        \fi
        }
    
    \path (O-3) --++ (1,0) |- (O-4) node[pos=0.2] {\vdots}; %Vdots beteween y_3 and y_k
        
    % Connect every node in the input layer with every node in the
    % hidden layer.
    \foreach \source in {1,...,4}
        \foreach \dest in {1,...,5}
            \path (I-\source) edge (H1-\dest);

    % connect all hidden stuff
    \foreach [remember=\N as \lastN (initially 1)] \N in {2,...,\Nhidden}
       \foreach \source in {1,...,5}
           \foreach \dest in {1,...,5}
               \path (H\lastN-\source) edge (H\N-\dest);

    % Connect every node in the last hidden layer with the output layer
       \foreach \source in {1,...,5}
           \foreach \dest in {1,...,4}
               \path (H3-\source) edge (O-\dest);
               

    
    % Annotate the layers
    
    \node[annot,left of=hl1] {Input layer};
    \node[annot,right of=hl\Nhidden] {Output layer};
    \end{scope}
    
    \draw [very thick,decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt}] (2,0) -- (8,0) node [midway,above=10pt] {Hidden layers};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```